# How to perform auto start of my python script on Mac?

Tags: python, macos, scheduled-tasks

I have script on mac that was written on Python (Pycharm), and now I want to run it once a day. How can I perform it?

I know about Task Scheduler for Windows, but I didn't found something build-in on Mac.

I also will be glad to perform it using not tool, but little script or plist or something else.

Script that I want to run is here (file main.py):

```
from package_suits.suits import *


def main():
    suits.runner(sys.argv[1], sys.argv[2], sys.argv[3])


main()
```

Comment: Can you run your script from the command line? Have you looked at cron (crontab)?

Comment: Sorry, didn't. Now I am trying to run it using Automator. Edited description.